# A Land Between Two Worlds

Tags: riddle, geography, poetry

> West of the Meridian,
>   Opposite of the Indian.
>
> A Frozen Land,
>   Its Discovery Unplanned.
>
> The Tomb of Cold,
>   A Rift Taking Hold.
>
> Land of Flames and Ice,
>   From Endless Night to Midnight Sun.

Comment: If fictional, it could have been "Punk Hazard" from One Piece.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Iceland?

A land Between Two Worlds:

> The two worlds are hot and cold. "Hot" being volcanoes, sand, lava fields, geothermal hot pools, and warmth from the gulf stream. "Cold" being glaciers and mountains.

West of the Meridian

> It is just west of the Prime Meridian.

Opposite of the Indian.

> In the North Atlantic ocean.

A Frozen Land,
Its Discovery Unplanned.

> Its discoverer Naddodd was trying to sail from Norway to the Faroes.

The Tomb of Cold,
A Rift Taking Hold.

> Iceland contains a rift valley.

Land of Flames and Ice,
From Endless Night to Midnight Sun.

> Depending on the time of year, days and nights last longer here.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: I thought between the old world and the new world... but your answer works better.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it could be

> Greenland

As,

West of the Meridian,

> It lies west of 0 degree longitude

Opposite of the Indian.

> In the northern hemisphere (As Indian ocean is in the southern hemisphere)

A Frozen Land,

> It is a land fully/almost covered with ice

Its Discovery Unplanned.

> Accidentally it was found, perhaps, while looking for other geographical places like North America/ North pole.

The Tomb of Cold,
A Rift Taking Hold.

> It is cold out there and rift separated this piece of land from mainland of Canada?!

Land of Flames and Ice,
From Endless Night to Midnight Sun.

> Perhaps dormant volcanoes and Norwegian authority over this land in earlier times(a kind of wild guess).

Comment: Really nice try :)